# Decrease the Timeout of only one request in a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

lets say i have a wcf service which has a one minute timeout for requests now how can i have one method which timeout for 5 secs instead of the global timeout ?

Comment: Publish that method in a separate service.

Comment: oh no that would break the whole logic since that method is made for checking the connectivity of its service , its like ping pong method : )

Answer (score 2):

Hasan Khan's popular comment is on the right track but I'd recommend you create two separate **contracts** (i.e. IServiceContractWithRegularTimeout and IPingPong) instead. A single service class would implement **both** interfaces and you would configure two endpoints for the service: one for IServiceContractWithRegularTimeout and one for IPingPong. This [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475079/wcf-iis-hosted-service-multiple-service-contracts-implemented-by-a-single-servic) shows an example of how you could do this.