# What's wrong with my wcf endpoints?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to create a wcf service with two endpoints, one SOAP 1.1 and the other SOAP 1.2. Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ProgramInformationWS.Properties.Settings.IMTConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DLADD00001;Initial Catalog=IMT;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService" behaviorConfiguration="ERPService.Behavior">
      <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="EnterpriseReportingWS.IERPService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="soap12" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="EnterpriseReportingWS.IERPService">
          <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
      </endpoint>         
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://MyServerHere/ERPService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ERPService.Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

What I am trying to configure here is that when I hit

```
http://caaditl20bz3.national.edu/ERPService/EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService.svc/soap
```

I get SOAP 1.1 and when I hit

```
http://caaditl20bz3.national.edu/ERPService/EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService.svc/soap12
```

I get SOAP 1.2.  However, the behavior I am getting is that neither of those resolve, and the only way I can access my service is from

http://caaditl20bz3.national.edu/ERPService/EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService.svc

What have I screwed up?

**UPDATE:**  By removing the wshttpbinding endpoint and using the basichttpbinding endpoint only in my config, I can get get SOAP 1.1.  What do I need to do to be able to make both available?

Comment: you need to remove the base address in the config for a start - for IIS hosting the base address is the .svc file

Comment: I just followed your suggestion.  after removing the base address, I couldn't access the service from http://caaditl20bz3.national.edu/EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService.svc/soap12 or http://caaditl20bz3.national.edu/EnterpriseReportingWS.ERPService.svc

Comment: or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Side-note; Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182725/multiple-endpoints-under-iis although that one is also unanswered. If someone finds an answer, they may want to apply it to both questions.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS? What is the machine name and virtual directory name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior" name="WcfTest.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" contract="WcfTest.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
      <endpoint address="/basic/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfTest.IService1" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In the above example I put `wsHttpBinding` at the root address http://server/service1.svc while `basicHttpBinding` can be found at http://server/service1.svc/basic/.  Note that you will not be able to see http://server/service1.svc/basic/ in a browser but that does not mean that it is not there.

To add a reference to the `wsHttpBinding` endpoint in Visual Studio just add a service reference as you would normally do.  To add a reference to the `basicHttpBinding` endpoint, go to the advanded settings dialog of the "Add service reference" screen and choose "Add Web Reference".

Note that to generate the client proxies for the `basicHttpBinding` endpoint you have to use http://server/service1.svc and **not** http://server/service1.svc/basic/ when adding the web reference.  But if you take a closer look at the generated .config file on the client you will see that it uses the /basic/ endpoint as it should:

```
<endpoint address="http://server/Service1.svc/basic/"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="Service1Reference.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
```