# WCF service exposing 2 endpoints on 2 different service contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, endpoint, servicecontract

I have an WCF service which I am trying to configure so that it exposes 2 endpoints, refering to different functionalities, under different URLs.

What I want to have is **Service1**, exposing methods A, B, C, and **Service2**, exposing methods D, E.
I want to be able to browse both **localhost/WebServiceName/Service1/Service.svc** and **localhost/WebServiceName/Service2/Service.svc**.

Other applications referencing **localhost/WebServiceName/Service1/Service.svc** should see only the interface containing the methods A, B and C. They should not see anything regarding **Service2** interface. And for **Service2** likewise.

So far I have defined two interfaces in my WCF service, **I_Service1** and **I_Service2**.

I have added two endpoints in my web.config like so:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service1/" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebServiceName.I_Service1" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" />
<endpoint address="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service2/" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WebServiceName.I_Service2" bindingConfiguration="Binding2" />
```

The suggestion of using full address in the enpoint comes from here: [Multiple endpoints under IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182725/multiple-endpoints-under-iis?rq=1)

But still, I can't browse **localhost/WebServiceName/Service1/Service.svc**. I receive:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

I can successfully browse *localhost/WebServiceName/Service.svc* and the wsdl includes methods A, B, C, D, E. But this should be wrong in the behaviour I want.

Is there something that I have missed?

UPDATE: Following this article http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.ro/2011/09/exposing-multiple-binding-types-for.html I created two different contract services for those endpoints. But currently I am seing only **Service1** when I browse it. **Service2** apparently does not exist (HTTP 404 error related issues appear).

The configuration looks like:

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceName.ServiceBehavior1" name="WebServiceName.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
     contract="WebServiceName.I_Service1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service1/Service.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
   </service>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceName.ServiceBehavior2" name="WebServiceName.Service2">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
     contract="WebServiceName.I_Service2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service2/Service.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
   </service>
  </services>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment my solution to this problem was incorporating two .svc files in my webservice to separate the two interfaces.
Such, I have **localhost/WebServiceName/Service1.svc** and **localhost/WebServiceName/Service2.svc**.

With the endpoint configuration

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceName.ServiceBehavior1" name="WebServiceName.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
     contract="WebServiceName.I_Service1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service1.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
   </service>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceName.ServiceBehavior2" name="WebServiceName.Service2">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding2"
     contract="WebServiceName.I_Service2" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WebServiceName/Service1.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
   </service>
  </services>
```

This solution is not necessary the best one (if a client really wants, it can find that this service exposes 2 different interfaces, but I can secure them with different credentials/tokens). But at the moment I will go with it.

Answer (score 4):

The way I've always done this is as follows: set a single "base address" for the service and specify the endpoint addresses as different text to append onto that base address...

```
 <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="FirstEndpointAddress" binding="netTcpBinding"
      name="FirstEndpointName"
      contract="MyNamespace.FirstEndpointContract" />
    <endpoint address="SecondEndpointAddress" binding="netTcpBinding"
      name="SecondEndpointName"
      contract="MyNamespace.SecondEndpointContract" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8733/MyBaseAddress" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

So in your case the base address might be `localhost/WebServiceName` and the endpoint address for endpoint 1 might be `Service1/Service.svc`.  Likewise for endpoint 2 it might be `Service2/Service.svc`.  I can see that you've followed advice to put the full address in the endpoint address, but all I can say is I've done it this way with success.

Comment: Even with this approach, I get the HTTP 404 error for localhost:8733/MyBaseAddress/FirstEndpointName/Service.svc (althought when I try to add an service reference in a client apparently localhost:8733/MyBaseAddress/Service.svc is seen while discovering services, with both interfaces which is bad in my case). Can there be a configuration error in terms of IIS, not web.config? I tried generating two Virtual Directories for the two endpoints, but both virtual directories get binded to the first endpoint's interface.

Comment: Unless you've given one of your endpoints the address "FirstEndpointName/Service.svc" I wouldn't expect the address you've used to work. Remember endpoint names and endpoint addresses are different things.

Comment: The ultimate address becomes: localhost:8733/MyBaseAddress/Service.svc/FirstEndpointAddress
and localhost:8733/MyBaseAddress/Service.svc/SecondEndpointAddress
In the client code: var svcClient = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("SecondEndpointName");

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make the thing which you described. All of this succeed. Please do'nt be angry if some of steps are obvious for you. So:

1. Create WCF Service Application Project.
2. Add two WCF Service items (by default will be create interface and svc file).
3. Create Web Application project.
4. Add two Service References (Right click on Web App Project ==> Add Service Reference) by using 'Discover' button (two web services should be visible).
5. That's all.

By default I got the following Web.config in Web Application project:

```
     <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3597/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3597/Service2.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" contract="ServiceReference2.IService2"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService2" />
</client>
```

You can try to rebuild WCF project and Update WebReferences.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with stating obvious steps; most time they are those we forget. Nonetheless, my question is about how to configure a single Web Service with 2 endpoints, not two different Web Services. Also, the configuration part is about what should be configured in that Web Service web.config, not in the web.config or app.config of applications referencing it.