# wcf client generated code requires constructor parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

When I follow the link the example it gives me

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
    InternalCommunicationClient client = new InternalCommunicationClient();

    // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

    // Always close the client.
    client.Close();
    }
}
```

But when I copy this code into a console, the `InternalCommunicationClient` requires 
(`InstanceContect` callback) as a parameter.

I have done wcf 2 years ago and this wasn't there back then. please help

Here is the web.conf code

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
<services>
  <service name="Workflowms.Web.webservices.Internalcommunication.InternalCommunication">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Workflowms.Web.webservices.Internalcommunication.IInternalCommunication" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Is it duplex service?

Comment: yes it is a duplex service

Comment: So, in duplex service it is required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574928(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps,

1. Expose end points
2. Make a Service Reference in your code
3. Use your above mentioned cod,

Comment: Here is a link for that,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742065/wcf-service-exposing-2-endpoints-on-2-different-service-contracts